# how can I serialize a multi user model that uses proxy

Tags: python-3.x, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am setting up an app that has 3 types of user admin, customer and Agent. I have my model setup this way:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            name=name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        try:
            user.save(using=self._db)
        except IntegrityError:
            raise IntegrityError('A user already uses this email')

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, name, password=password)
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class Types(models.TextChoices):
        CUSTOMER = "CUSTOMER", "Customer"
        AGENT = "AGENT", "Agent"
    type = models.CharField(_('Type'), max_length=50, choices=Types.choices, default=Types.CUSTOMER)
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email of the user'), unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name of the user'), max_length=100)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(_('Phone number of the user'), blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateField(_('Date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class CustomerManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args **kwargs).filter(type=User.Types.CUSTOMER)

class AgentManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args **kwargs).filter(type=User.Types.AGENT)

class Customer(User):
    '''proxy class for registering customer'''
    objects = CustomerManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.type = User.Types.CUSTOMER
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Agent(User):
    '''proxy class for registering Agent'''
    objects = AgentManager()
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.type = User.Types.AGENT
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am super new to Django and I saw this method in two scoops to Django and on Daniel Roy Greenfields YouTube channel

I have no idea how to serialize this so that I have two links on the frontend for signup one for customer and one for Agent

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you written your views and serializers file?

Comment: They are both based on user, and the only flag to say whether they are an `Agent` or `Customer` is on `type`, so you can just add handling to use the correct type depending on where/how they signup

Comment: I have not written the the views and serialisers because I have no idea how to go about it. all previous things I have worked used Django allauth and rest Framework for authentication.

@bdbd can you help with a template or in-depth explanation or resource to help

Comment: The scope is a bit broad so it would be better to get a use case where we can work on serializing the proxy models. For now I think to start, just work around the `User` model but keeping in mind to set type on the correct places, ie. if you are in an Agent sign up page assign type as agent.

Comment: so I am to write views for each user type because I wrote a view for user that uses all the fields I specify